# How to replace parameter values with column name in a json string in presto

Tags: sql, json, presto, trino

I have a table named *sampleTable* with values like this (please note that the columns can be up to key100, stating a small example for reducing the complexity of the example).

```
select * from sampleTable;
```

| key1 | key2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1111 | 2222 |

I am trying to generate a query which creates one JSON string which can include these column values to one JSON String per row like the below mentioned format.

```
 '{"keys":{"key1":"1111", "key2":"2222"}}'
```

What is the right way to do it through a presto query ?
My attempts are as given below:

**Attempt 1**

```
select 
    concat('{"keys":{"key1": ', a.key1, ',',
    '{"key2": ' ,a.key2, '}}') 
    AS keyJson 
from sampleTable ;
```

**Attempt 2**

```
select 
    replace(
        replace('{"keys":{"key1": $key1, "key2": $key2}}','$key1',d.key1), 
        '$key2',d.key2 ) 
    AS keyJson 
from sampleTable ;
```

Is there any simpler way to do this considering that the keys can be varying from key1 to key100. For context, I am dynamically generating the query from a java program. Appending strings using the StringBuilder approach in both of these cases becomes complex in case of presence of multiple keys.

Comment: JSON operations should be carried out by [appropriate](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/json.html) JSON functions or casts. Manual string concatenation is a way full of errors

Comment: @astentx I agree. The problem that I am facing is that I am not dealing with pure strings as such, instead, I want the parameter values inside the json to be replaced with column names. Can you please suggest how this can be performed with JSON operations mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idiomatic way is to construct a `ROW` value and then cast it to `JSON`:

- First, construct a row from the columns: `row(key1, key2, key3)`. This will produce an anonymous row type (i.e., a row with unnamed fields)
- Second, cast the value to a row with named fields: `CAST(... AS ROW(key1 VARCHAR, key2 VARCHAR, key3 VARCHAR))`. The field names will become the keys when the row is converted to `JSON`.
- Finally, cast the resulting value to `JSON`: `CAST(... AS JSON)`

Here's a complete example:

```sql
WITH data(key1, key2, key3) AS (
    VALUES
        ('1111', '2222', '3333')
)
SELECT
    CAST(
        CAST(row(key1, key2, key3) AS ROW(key1 VARCHAR, key2 VARCHAR, key3 VARCHAR)) AS JSON)
FROM data
```

which produces:

```
                    _col0
---------------------------------------------
 {"key1":"1111","key2":"2222","key3":"3333"}
(1 row)
```

Tested with [Trino 359](https://trino.io/) ([formerly known as PrestoSQL](https://trino.io/blog/2020/12/27/announcing-trino.html))

Comment: This does not work using [Presto](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/json.html) because "When casting from ROW to JSON, the result is a JSON array rather than a JSON object. This is because positions are more important than names for rows in SQL."